# Could not deduce template argument for 'Node<T> *' from 'int'

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, linked-list, xor-linkedlist

I am currently trying to implement XOR linked list in c++. I tried using template to make it generic. This error pops up during compile time and I cannot get past this.

I tried googling XOR linked list using templates but it seems that there are no implementations of it so far.

XORlinkedlist.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include<iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node *XORcode;
};

template <typename T>
Node<T> * XOR(struct Node<T> *x, struct Node<T> *y)
{
    return (Node<T>*)( (uintptr_t)(x) ^ (uintptr_t)(y) );
}

template <typename T>
class XORlinkedList
{
private:
    Node<T> *top, *last;
public:
    XORlinkedList()
    {
        top = last = NULL;
    }

    void addAtBegin(T data)
    {
        Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>;
        temp->data = data;

        temp->XORcode = XOR(top, NULL);    //*****ERROR SHOWN IN THIS LINE HERE*****
        if(top != NULL)
            top->XORcode = XOR(top->XORcode, temp);
        top = temp;
    }

    ~XORlinkedList()
    {
        Node<T> *temp, *storeCode;
        temp = top;
        storeCode = NULL;

        while(top != NULL)
        {
            temp = top;
            top = XOR(top->XORcode, storeCode);
            std::cout<<temp->data<<" deleted\n";
            storeCode = temp->XORcode;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
};
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "XORlinkedlist.h"

int main()
{
    XORlinkedList<int> X;

    X.addAtBegin(3);
    X.addAtBegin(4);
    X.addAtBegin(5);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

> error C2784: 'Node *XOR(Node *,Node *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'Node *' from 'int'

Comment: Similarly, your `return (Node<T>*)( (uintptr_t)(x) ^ (uintptr_t)(y) );` makes no sense. Doing bit operations on two addresses of objects is not usually going to give you the address of some other object, and doesn't create any such object either. Operations on the `data` member would make more sense. Also, consider using `set::unique_ptr<Node>` everywhere you have a `Node*` (except probably member `last`).

Comment: But that would be simply against the concept of XOR linked list by not taking addresses. Yeah, using smart pointers is a good idea...

Comment: Oh, I see. It's a value that doesn't actually itself point at a `Node`. (I'd probably use a `uintptr_t` instead of `Node<T>*` as the `XORcode` member.)

Comment: @aschepler but doesn't uintptr_t same size as Node pointer would occupy? So it doesn't matter?

Comment: Right, it doesn't much matter for technical reasons. It would just be my preference for code clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiler can not deduce the argument type because `NULL` is not a pointer type. You should overload your method, like this, by using `nullptr`, which is an object of an object of type `std::nullptr_t`:

```
// nullptr overload. 
template <typename T>
Node<T> * XOR(struct Node<T> *x, std::nullptr_t)
{
  return x; // X⊕0 = X
}   

template <typename T>
Node<T> * XOR(struct Node<T> *x, struct Node<T> *y)
{
    return (Node<T>*)( (uintptr_t)(x) ^ (uintptr_t)(y) );
}
```

and then, call the method like this:

```
temp->XORcode = XOR(top, nullptr);
```

PS: Your constructor's logic seems flawed, probably resulting in a segmentation fault. Read more in Wikipedia or in [this](https://iq.opengenus.org/xor-linked-list/) C implementation (with an explanation).

Comment: There is no guarantee that `NULL` be an `int`. Using a `nullptr_t` overload with `nullptr` would be a much better idea.

Comment: @Holt I agree, answer updated, looks better now? :)

Comment: @gsamaras Yes ;)

Comment: I figured that XOR(A,0) is A itself, so I removed all functions of XOR which called it using NULL. Turns out that was better, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, as I have in my answer @krossMett, after visiting Wikipedia. I am not sure what's better, they are equivalent in terms of logic, you should think of what would improve readability. If you do it the way you say, then write a comment at the first time of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify explicitly a function template argument like

```
temp->XORcode = XOR<T>( top, NULL );
```

or

```
temp->XORcode = XOR<T>( top, nullptr );
```